# Scipy as dependency on travis-ci and No module named _csr

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, travis-ci

I am trying to setup a build on travis for my project, which has scipy as a dependency. All is built and installed fine, until nosetests is run. I am getting a `No module named _csr` error. I can see it is a part of scipy and sparsetools subpackage.

```
$ nosetests
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named '_csr')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.py", line 15, in     swig_import_helper fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_csr', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.3_with_system_site_packages/lib/python3.3/imp.py",     line 239, in find_module
  raise ImportError(_bootstrap._ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
  ImportError: No module named '_csr'
```

The build log can be seen here: https://travis-ci.org/tdi/pyPEPA/builds/9277243

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use virtualenvs for Python tests on Travis, so you can't install packages using `apt-get`, but you have to use `pip` instead.

I believe this should work (in `.travis.yml`):

```
language: python
python:
  - "3.3"
install: 
  - pip install --use-mirrors pyparsing
  - pip install --use-mirrors matplotlib
script: nosetests
virtualenv:
  system_site_packages: true
before_install:
  - pip install numpy
  - pip install python-dateutil
  - pip install pytz
  - pip install scipy
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -qq libatlas-dev libatlas-base-dev liblapack-dev gfortran
notifications: 
  email: false
```

I'm not sure if `libatlas` is a Python extension as well. If it is, then you will have to install that using `pip` too.

For more information, see [our Python documentation](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/python/).

Comment: Ok, I tried the same config couple of times and it did not work but now it works. Thank you.

Comment: I have to wait 7 more hours to give you bounty :)